# slow loading content with .load() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jQuery and jQuery UI on my website. I use this segment of script.

> $("content").load("newContent.php");

Speed of loading the content is slower whenever I try to reload this content. My question is Why and how i solved this issues. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

Run a faster server? You're biggest latency is a network one.

Only thing that could improve it is passing only the required data and stop transferring the entire UI. e.g. If you're really only updating two `<span>`s (for instance), return back JSON with those two values and update them in-line.

Comment: my page is now only on localhost